# Indian citizen working in USA (on a work Visa) planning to get married to a citizen of Ireland

Tags: marriage, working, ireland, residence-cards

My Irish boyfriend and I are planning to get married soon. He lives in Turkey and I am currently working in the USA (on a work visa). We might get married in court here in The USA. After marriage, we are planning to move to Ireland but have work related queries. When will I be able to start working in Ireland? Also, he is more leaning towards moving to Spain (instead of Ireland). How will it work out with respect to work and residency visa and how soon I can start working?

Comment: It will be easier for you in Spain than in Ireland.

Comment: Slight elaboration on phoog's commnet: If you go to Spain, you are operating under mostly EU law, which has lots of nice free applications involved, automatic rights, and quick turnarounds. After you've reached a stage of where you are 'settled', pretty much the entire EU is then open to you.